# SQL query performance with OR clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

This SQL query takes **10** second:

```
SELECT * FROM A a
JOIN B b on a.idB = b.idB
JOIN C c on b.idC = c.idC
JOIN D d on c.idD = d.idD
JOIN E e  ON((e.perimeterId = a.idA AND e.level = 3) 
          OR (e.perimeterId = b.idB AND e.level = 2) 
          OR (e.perimeterId = c.idC AND e.level = 1)
          OR (e.perimeterId = d.idD AND e.level = 0))
```

Changing **OR** clause with **CASE**, the query takes **3**  second:

```
SELECT * FROM A a
JOIN B b on a.idB = b.idB
JOIN C c on b.idC = c.idC
JOIN D d on c.idD = d.idD
JOIN E e  ON (
               CASE e.level
                    when 3 then a.idA
                    when 2 then b.idB
                    when 1 then c.idC
                    when 0 then d.idD
               END
             ) = e.perimeterId
```

If i execute the query with separate OR clause, the queries are executed instantly
Withour **OR** clause :

```
SELECT * FROM A a
JOIN B b on a.idB = b.idB
JOIN C c on b.idC = c.idC
JOIN D d on c.idD = d.idD
JOIN E e  ON (e.perimeterId = a.idX AND e.level = X)
```

How to rewrite my query to be execute instantly or with high performance possible?

Comment: If you limit your data with `WHERE e.level in (0,1,2,3)` what will became with first query?

Comment: Can you clarify: a) how many distinct values of `e.level` you have? b) do you have duplicate values in tables `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` for `idA`, `idB`, `idC`?

Comment: Why are you joining with a,b,c,d but not selecting anything from them? You could simply do a `select e.* from e join a on e.preimeterid = a.ida where e.level = 3 union all select e.* from e join b ...`

Comment: it was a mistake i updated my post @AlexYu

Comment: Ah. I see. But the questions remains the same. Let's rephrase them: a) Do you have duplicates in your result query? If you add DISTINCT to your queries does result changes? b) How many distinct values of `e.level` you have? Are they in range `[0..4]` or e.g. `[0..1024]`? c) if you have a lot of `e.level`s - what will become if you add `WHERE e.level in (0,1,2,3)` or `WHERE e.level <4` and such?

Comment: @AlexYu yes there are duplicates as the result after disticnt is different, i have 7 level, i added the condition `where e.level>=0` as other level are (-3,-2,-1) but the query still slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only want columns from `e`, so I would write this using `exists`:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM E e
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM a
              WHERE e.perimeterId = a.idA AND e.level = 3
             ) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM a JOIN
                   b
                   ON a.idB = b.idB
              WHERE e.perimeterId = b.idA AND e.level = 2
             ) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM a JOIN
                   b
                   ON a.idB = b.idB JOIN
                   c
                   ON c.idC = b.idC
              WHERE e.perimeterId = c.idA AND e.level = 1
             ) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM a JOIN
                   b
                   ON a.idB = b.idB JOIN
                   c
                   ON c.idC = b.idC JOIN
                   d
                   ON d.idD = c.idD
              WHERE e.perimeterId = d.idA AND e.level = 0
             );
```

I'm not 100% sure that the `JOIN`s are needed in the subqueries, but I've left them in anyway.

Comment: First query as written by OP is duplicating rows. Is intentionally or not is unknown. And I suppose that performance hit could be filtering e.level values to `(0,1,2,3)`

Comment: @AlexYu . . . I'm quite aware the queries aren't exactly the same.  In my experience, the duplicates are not desirable, but the OP may have a different use-case.

Comment: @GordonLinoff after rewriting my query following your example, it works just fine, Thanks a lot, i will accept your post as answer

Answer (score 0):

1)create indexes on a.idB, b.idB, b.idC, c.idC, c.idD, d.idD, e.perimeterId, e.level

2)
Try this

```
SELECT * FROM A a
JOIN B b on a.idB = b.idB
JOIN C c on b.idC = c.idC
JOIN D d on c.idD = d.idD
JOIN E e  ON(e.perimeterId = a.idA AND e.level = 3) 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM A a
JOIN B b on a.idB = b.idB
JOIN C c on b.idC = c.idC
JOIN D d on c.idD = d.idD
JOIN E e  ON(e.perimeterId = a.idB AND e.level = 2) 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM A a
JOIN B b on a.idB = b.idB
JOIN C c on b.idC = c.idC
JOIN D d on c.idD = d.idD
JOIN E e  ON(e.perimeterId = a.idC AND e.level = 1) 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM A a
JOIN B b on a.idB = b.idB
JOIN C c on b.idC = c.idC
JOIN D d on c.idD = d.idD
JOIN E e  ON(e.perimeterId = a.idD AND e.level = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most performance problems are solved with well-built indexes, in your clause always try to use the primary indeces if you don't have to create a corresponding columns of filters.